# JQuery TokenInput not displaying search result

Tags: java, jquery, playframework-2.0, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

I am using jQuery Tokeninput to display the emails of user, Actually I am trying to invite users. When I click on the input text and type some email it always say no result even if that email exists.

My JS is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://localhost:9000/api/customers"
       $("#members").tokenInput(url, {
           theme: "facebook"
        });
    });
  </script>
```

My controller action is

```
  public static Result apiCustomers(){
    List<Customer> customerList = Model.coll(Customer.class).find().toArray();
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Customer c : customerList){
        emails.add(c.email);
    }

    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
    result.put("emails", Json.toJson(emails));      
    return ok(result);
  }
```

when I type something the text input it calls the apiCustomer action and the response looks like which is a valid json string

```
{"emails":["abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com","asd@gmail.com","bob@gmail.com"]}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the Tokeninput plugin but it seems like you're not outputting correct json. While your action is generating a valid json string, it's not the json string that the plugin expects.

Refer to the [Tokeninput documentation](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/#installation--setup) for the correct format.